# AngularJS Extending Default Options before Compiling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a simple table directive.  I need to extend the columns with the default width if not passed in the options.

Currently, I copy and extend the options onto a new columns array so I can avoid setting the columns once and then resetting them again thus causing 2 digests.

Is there an ideal way to extend these onto the existing object pre-compile that would avoid the double digest hit?

```js
class DataTable {
  constructor($scope){
    var ColumnDefaults = { width: 50 };
    $scope.columns = $scope.options.columns.map((c) => {
      return angular.extend(angular.copy(ColumnDefaults), c);
    });

  }
}

function Directive(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'DataTable',
    scope: {
      options: '=',
      values: '=',
      onSelect: '&'
    },
    controllerAs: 'dt',
    template: 
      `<div class="dt material">
        <dt-header columns="columns"></dt-header>
        <dt-body values="values" columns="columns"></dt-body>
        <dt-footer></dt-footer>
      </div>`,
    link: function($scope, $elm, $attrs){
      //console.log($scope.options)
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hook into the pre function on compile of the directive your able to get ahold of the dom before the directive init's.

```
compile: function(tElem, tAttrs){
  return {
    pre: function($scope, $elm, $attrs, ctrl){
      ... code here ...
    }
  }
}
```